# How to keep track of destroyed activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

Let's say I have activity A which has a button to open another instance of activity A. Let's say I have opened 5 instances of activity A this way. If I enable the option "Don't keep activities", how do I keep the same state for each activity when pressing back from the last one?

I was thinking of using activity hashcode(), but apparently it is different every time the activity is recreated. Do I have to keep an array of instance states?

Comment: look at the activity life cycle https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activitylifecycle/starting.html     when you go from one activity to another the first activity become pasue and so for the next instance one when you are on the way back onresume is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are deliberately destroying your activites, the only way i can think of is to save the current state of your activity before being destroyed in [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). Here, you can save the current state yourself in a `Bundle` which will be passed to both [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and `onCreate()`. There you can get the data from the `Bundle` and do proper initializations.

Comment: I thought that but what key should I be using for each instance state? They are the same activity so if I use the same key each instance state would be overwritten.

Comment: Ok...did you try it though? A part of me says backstack should keep track of proper instance restoration.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

you need to save your activity state
.
.
.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: But wouldn't using the same key mean overwriting the instance state?

Comment: please also include the key parts of the article inside your answer. this enables users to view the details even if the link is inaccessible.

Comment: you have to set logic as you want. but for get back state you need to save those.